# SQL : build a query that reads from a file

Tags: sql, subquery

i have a table with column name,add,no tel. ( millions of rows)
i need to pull a list of names ( like hundreds) from the table.
the straight forward way is like this...

`select * from table where name = name1 or name = name2 .....or name = name300`

i tried to make it more simpler,
i import the list of name into another table,say table2.
then i do a subquery.

```
select * from table where name like '%'+(select * from table2)+'%'
```

but it did not work.

please help how i can accomplish this efficiently.
thank u.

Answer (score 2):

Just join the two tables:

```
Select a.* from tableA a join tableB b on a.name = b.name
```